# Incorrect solution of diffusion equation with Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: numerical-integration, differential-equations

I want to set up a PDE model, which takes a two-dimensional diffusion equation into account. The key problem is that I have some trouble in solving the two-dimensional diffusion equation numerically. Consider the following code:

```
L = 10;
T = 10;
system = {
   D[c[x, y, t], {t, 1}] == D[c[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + D[c[x, y, t], {y, 2}],
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][c][0, y, t] == 0,
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][c][L, y, t] == 0,
   c[x, 0, t] == c[x, L, t],
   c[x, y, 0] == 1
   };
sol = NDSolve[system, c, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, {t, 0, T}];
Manipulate[Plot3D[Evaluate[c[x, y, t] /. sol], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}], {{t,T}, 0, T}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see  for `t = 10` there are artifacts at the two edges where the Neumann conditions were applied.

Obviously, `c[x, y, t] = 1` solves the system and since this is the initial condition Mathematica should have no trouble to compute it numerically. It tried various ODE solvers (`"ImplicitRungeKutta"`, `"BDF"`, `"Adams"`), but it seems that there is some problem with the spatial discretization, perhaps because of the Neumann boundary condition for the variable `x`.

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: You could try increasing `PrecisionGoal` and/or `AccuracyGoal`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to use a pseudospectral difference order, explained [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePDE.html#PDE:1.2.4).

This then works:

```
L = 10;
T = 10;
system = {D[c[x, y, t], {t, 1}] == 
    D[c[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + D[c[x, y, t], {y, 2}], 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][c][0, y, t] == 0,
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][c][ L, y, t] == 0,
   c[x, 0, t] == c[x, L, t],
   c[x, y, 0] == 1};
sol = NDSolve[system, c, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, {t, 0, T}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}];
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Evaluate[c[x, y, T] /. sol], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, 
  PlotRange -> {0.9, 1.1}], {{t, T}, 0, T}]
```

Other things you might want to try is to use a finer grid, also explained in the above document.